# How can i get all available printers in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I´m developing a program that let you choose the printer you want to print on, for that i need to get all available printers on my system

ActionScript 3,

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what kind of permission level you'd be running on, but the property you'd normally be looking for to get that information is [PrintJob.printers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html#printers).

If that property is not available, you can't get to a list, you'll have to just trigger a print dialog and have the user choose a printer from there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't access the printers directly, much like the file system (aside from in AIR) you delegate the print dialogue out to the operating system:
http://www.files.riacodes.com/flash_print/